# Horizontal scroll with mouse wheel on horizontal list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm attempting a horizontal scroll with the mouse wheel, but doesn't seem to work.

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3j1x47a/)

My main class `.selector` is the one with scrollable `overflow`

This is JS I am trying to initialise the scroll with

```
 $('.selector').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

This is the example I am using for horizontal scroll https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/

Thanks in advance for any help!

**EDIT:** Thanks all, I forgot jQuery in the Fiddle yeah sorry, but when I was testing on localhost I was using jQuery 1.11.1 so maybe that was the case. Cheers guys

Comment: In your fiddle you didn't include the `jQuery` link. I fixed this in: http://jsfiddle.net/a3j1x47a/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just forget to add JQuery to your html

http://jsfiddle.net/902tjbzz/

`jquery.js` : http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Answer (score 6):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/66pbar78/):

```
$('.selector').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
    $(this).scrollLeft(this.scrollLeft + (-delta * 40));
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Also, you did not include jQuery in your fiddle.

**EDIT**

Actually, the only problem was that you did not include jQuery, your initial code works fine.

Comment: Sorry mate, not sure who downvoted you. Upvoted you back up.

Answer (score 1):

First thing: in yor jsfiddle you forget to include jquery.

The second thing: I changed `$('.selector').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {` to `$('.selector').on("mousewheel", function(e, delta) {` and only then I could see that event is triggered.

Also check your `scrollLeft` property update logic. Don't forget about direction (left, right), so in some case you should add value insead of subtract it